# Using solc with Truffle

Tags: contract-development, truffle, truffle-config

As per the title, I haven't found anywhere (neither in Truffle Docs nor googling) how to use solc with Truffle (I am on Ubuntu 16.04).

For example, let's say I wanna use new `require` and `assert` features of Solidity 0.4.10, how can I use those directives within Truffle? Is it even possible?

Thanks.